# Why not open activity from broadcast receiver when application closed in android?

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

> Code given below.this is the Onreceive method

```
Intent i = new Intent(context,ToastActivity.class);
i.putExtra("INCOMING_NUMBER", num);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);                   
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: please tell me i have problem in lg device when application closed then after no activity display when incoming call from broadcast receiver

Comment: Receive any error?

Comment: where your registering the Broadcast receicever

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //start activity
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClassName("com.package", "com.package.ToastActivity");
    i.putExtra("INCOMING_NUMBER", num);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

And plz make sure your Broadcast Receiver are working.

Comment: in xiomi redmi prime 2 for working but lg device in not working? where is actuall problem

Comment: yes but also work in lg device but slow process reason not opening activity when call is incoming when application killed after

Comment: can you post your full receiver code with manifest receiver ?

Comment: <receiver android:name="CallReceiver" android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter > <action android:name="YouNeverKill"/></intent-filter>
             <intent-filter >
                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                   </intent-filter>
                    <intent-filter >
                   <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
                   </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: this is my code and i have one question when i clear task second time that time not call ontask remove method what is problem

Comment: Try to put Receiver class name with path(means full package like com.example.CallReceiver and sorry i am not getting your other question.

Comment: any idea when i open activity over screen then call is ringing then call can not receive in android